# C# How to trigger a file download when clicking a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, webforms

I have a ASP.NET Webform with only a button on it. I also have a 1 gb zipfile on my computer.

When I click the button, I want to trigger a download of my 1 gb zipfile in Internet Explorer. During the download process, I want to be able to pause and resume the download.

Iv been trying to figure out how to accomplish this, with little success. How can I create this functionality?

Iv found a function on MSDN called:

```
TriggerFileDownload
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg593105(v=vs.85).aspx

But I am not sure how to utilize this. All I have now currently is the button's OnClick event. Does anyone know how I can make this button accomplish this?

Comment: The `TriggerFileDownload` function you mention is for desktop applications that host an IE browser helper object, it has nothing to do with ASP.NET applications. However, even if you were on the right path, what you want to do is not trivial. You could use the `Response.TransmitFile` in an aspx page and point your button to that page, but that will not give you the ability to pause and resume the download, for that you need AJAX and a lot more code...

Comment: Here's an example implementing buffering https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Implement-resume-in-aspnet-c1bbde36

Comment: @Scotty This is perfect, and does exactly what I needed. If you repost this as an answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on MSDN which uses an HttpHandler and file buffering technique to achieve download pausing and resuming

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Implement-resume-in-aspnet-c1bbde36